# How to get time value from jquery timepicker.?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timepicker

I am trying to get values from i select time in my time picker but so far I am not getting any values in return and not even in my html timepicker input showing any value inside,

I tried some methods but not successful yet,

**Method 1:**

```
$('#datetimepicker4').on('selectTime', function() {
    var time = $('#datetimepicker4').timepicker('getTime');
    alert(time);
    // this will be a Date object that includes the time
});
```

**Method 2:**

```
$("#datetimepicker4").on('change paste keyup', function(){
    var time = $(this).val();
    alert(time);
    var getTime = time.split(":"); //split time by colon
    var hours = parseInt(getTime[0])+2; //add two hours
    //set new time
    var newTime = hours+":"+getTime[1];
    //set time picker
    $("#datetimepicker5").timepicker('option',{'minTime': newTime});
});
```

I am debugging by try alert even not getting alert so my both functions are not working that means, even no console error relate to time pickers for selection I found, I want to be able to set min time 3 hours for current time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't think so you need a getTime you can simply select input box value.

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $('input.timepicker').timepicker();
        $("#getdate").on('click',function(){
           $("#time").text($("#timepicker").val())
        })
    });

})(jQuery);
```

if you want on change of timepicker use below code

```
 $('document').ready(function(){
                $('#time').timepicker();
                $('#time').on('changeTime', function() {
                    var x = $("#time").val();
                    $('#d_time').text(x);
                });
            });
```

see working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/n6sft0qr/9/)

updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Negirox/b2mt9foL/4/)

Comment: working example you showed it look fine but i need this to be done on change of time not click of button,

Comment: its working with button click and .blur other events but no one change i have used on change for other inputs too for some validations is that might conflicting but i am not getting any error on console

Comment: It's working so i have approve your answer thanks alot but, it not working on my site,